# Counting problem with set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of a set $M$ and define $S_0 := \{A,B\}$. Now for $i \ge 0$ define $S_{i+1}$ inductively as the collection of subsets of $M$ taking the form $C \cup D$, $C \cap D$ or $M - C$ where $C,D \in S_i$. What is the largest possible number of elements in $S = \bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty} S_i$.

The answer is $16$ and I am okay with working it out but my question is: It seems like the finite-ness of $S$ relies on the fact that no new subsets are created with these operations after several iterations. 1) Is there a general rule that gives the number of steps needed for this sort of process to terminate given $n$ allowed set operations? 2) Is there also a rule for the size of a similar $S$ given a different $S_0$ with a different number of starting sets. 3) Does the number of steps depend on the type of operation allowed (e.g. "normal" ones like intersections and unions and such, not arbitrary operations I make up)?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  Any element of $S_i$ is a union of sets of the form $A\setminus B$, $B\setminus A$, $A\cap B$, and $(A\cup B)^\text{c}$.